# Why can't I use the "r" tag anymore

Tags: support, tags

Recently I realize that I cannot tag any questions with `r` anymore. Why is that? 
Approximately 1700 questions are tagged with `r` an I used this tag before too, actually I have a feed for this tag. What's wrong?

Comment: No repro. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3459867/revisions

Comment: Sorry I do not get this at all. What does no repro mean? what's the link pointing to?

Comment: It means he can't reproduce your problem. The link points to an edit history showing that he added the r tag to a question, which demonstrates that adding the tag works fine.

Comment: welcome to Meta!  You're going to have to provide some more information if you want this to be resolved.  You said "anymore"; have you been able to tag questions as `[r]` before?  Have you changed any system/browser settings recently?  What were the exact steps you took in your attempt to tag the question?  Did you try multiple times and on different questions?  Did you try to add `[r]` to a question that already had five tags?  (This is all just suggested information.  Use your judgment on what to include, &c.)

Comment: Obviously the problem is pirates.

Comment: @Rosinante What does "being pirates" mean? (Except for the literal occupation as a violent sailors looting other ships as the case was common in earlier centuries.)

Comment: Look up national 'talk like a pirate' day.

Comment: Can not reproduce and can not find any correlation between Stackoverflow and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Talk_Like_a_Pirate_Day